# jQuery function scope and accessing the function outside the scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a jquery file with the following structure::

```
(function($) {

var MYTEST= {

       init: function() {
          alert('Hello World');
       }
       exec: function() {
            alert('function executed');
       }
    }

  $(function() {
     MYTEST.init();
  })

}(jQuery))
```

I want to access the second function ie, 'exec' in another file or outside the jQuery scope. to make it clear some thing like this::

```
 (function($) {

        var MYTEST= {
        .
        .
        }

 }(jQuery))

    $(function() {
         MYTEST.exec();
    })
```

I know the above code will not work, just to get idea. How can I access that function outside(I actually not aware of the specific jargon to explain the situation in javascript, sorry for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to use the global scope with namespacing, this will allow you to use the object in different files as well.

```
(function($, win) {

    win.MYTEST= {

       init: function() {
          alert('Hello World');
       }
       exec: function() {
            alert('function executed');
       }
    }

}(jQuery, window))
```

If you are using ES6 and export & import you could use the module pattern (obviously ES6 is not a must here but it is nicer) :

```
const MYTESTModule = (function($) {

    return MYTEST= {

       init: function() {
          alert('Hello World');
       },
       exec: function() {
            alert('function executed');
       }
    };

}(jQuery));

export default MYTESTModule;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there any option without using 'win' global variable, and by just using  '$'

Comment: you can, the global scope always exist, even within the immediate fucntion scope. but it is a convention to declare what you are going to use within the function. some are also passing 'undefined' so that if someone will override it by mistake it will not affect them.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the function exec from your code. This is known as module pattern.

```
var MyTESTModule = (function($) {

   var MYTEST= {
       init: function() {
          alert('Hello World');
       }      
    }

   $(function() {
      Starling.init();
   })
   return {
    exec: function() {
       alert('function executed');
    }
   }
}(jQuery));
MYTESTModule.exec();
```